# Dockerfile for flask application with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, docker, flask

I'm new to Docker. I want to deploy my Flask application using Docker. [This](https://www.smartfile.com/blog/dockerizing-a-python-flask-application/) and various other tutorials show how to deploy a simple Flask app. But I'm having trouble applying the things on these tutorials to a more complicated Flask app. Specifically, my app has to have matplotlib. I'm having some trouble installing it using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

What are the necessary lines to add for the Dockerfile below?
I've tried adding `RUN sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` which asked me `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]` and I didn't know how to say `Y` under a Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Update OS
RUN sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Install Python
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip

# Install matplotlib and related packages
# TODO

# Add requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /webapp

# Install uwsgi Python web server
RUN pip install uwsgi
# Install app requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Create app directory
ADD . /webapp

# Set the default directory for our environment
ENV HOME /webapp
WORKDIR /webapp

# Expose port 8000 for uwsgi
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi", "--http", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--module", "app:app", "--processes", "1", "--threads", "8"]
```

Comment: You can use the `-y` flag, i.e. `RUN sudo apt-get install -y python-matplotlib`

Comment: Not your problem, but group your RUN, see Dockerfiles best practices